# How can I solve an equation with two changing variables in Mathematica?

Tags: nested, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I want to solve an equation for one value x and many values y. However, x should also change after a certain number of runs of y. I was thinking of a nested for-loop, as I am still relatively new to Mathematica. My idea was something like this:

`For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, For[j = 5, j < 10, j++, Print[i + j]]]`

Except that print, of course, is the equation. But I am of course open to better solutions. I hope I was able to express myself halfway understandably, as English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Perhaps Table[i+j,{j,5,9},{i,0,3}] or Table[Print[i+j],{j,5,9},{i,0,3}] will get you closer to what you want to do. If that isn't what you want then try to explain why this doesn't do what you are trying to do and I'll try again

Comment: Yes i think it help a lot

Comment: Similarly `Total /@ Tuples[{Range[0, 3], Range[5, 9]}]`